# Is there a way to solve this problem when submitting template driven form in angular 8

Tags: angular

SignUpComponent.html:10 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'valid' of undefined 
why do this happen?

Comment: Welcome to SO, you need to share some code, to reproduce your issue, then people can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the variable would not have been referanced to for which you want to get the property.

Try adding

```
<input #nameoftheinput ...>
```

Then take the value as

```
<span [hidden]="nameoftheinput.valid" > No errors </span>
```

This would work